# Nodejs Async_hooks Remove Context When i use await

Tags: node.js, async-hooks

Hi Everone I am using async_hook for request context
console.log("xxx",hook.getRequestContext())  // undefined because of i am using promise before

```
var hook = require('../../services/hooks.service');

const test11 = async (req,res)=>{


let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
let x = 0;

if (x == 0) {
  myResolve("OK");
} else {
  myReject("Error");
}
  });

 await myPromise

console.log("xxx",hook.getRequestContext())  // undefined because of i am using promise before
}
```

hook.service.js

```
       const asyncHooks = require('async_hooks');
     const { v4 } = require('uuid');
     const store = new Map();

      const asyncHook = asyncHooks.createHook({
      init: (asyncId, _, triggerAsyncId) => {
      if (store.has(triggerAsyncId)) {
        store.set(asyncId, store.get(triggerAsyncId))
     }
   },
    destroy: (asyncId) => {
    if (store.has(asyncId)) {
        store.delete(asyncId);
    }
   }
  });

    asyncHook.enable();

  const createRequestContext = (data, requestId = v4()) => {
 const requestInfo = { requestId, data };
 console.log(asyncHooks.executionAsyncId())
 store.set(asyncHooks.executionAsyncId(), requestInfo);
 return requestInfo;
 };

 const getRequestContext = () => {
 console.log(asyncHooks.executionAsyncId())
 return store.get(asyncHooks.executionAsyncId());
  };

module.exports = { createRequestContext, getRequestContext };
```

app.js

```
const hook = require('./src/services/hooks.service');

app.use((request, response, next) => {

const data = { headers: request.headers };
hook.createRequestContext(data);


next();
```

});

What should I do? I want to get context after the promise. but I am getting undefined
why i am getting undefined because asyncHooks.executionAsyncId() getting new id after promise